# Using the google-maps-utility-api's heat map with varying intensity of measurments

Tags: android, google-maps, heatmap

I am currently working on an application for android phones which will take measurements (doesn't matter what is being measured) and display a heatmap of the results. However, I want to produce this heatmap as a "weighted heatmap" using WeightedLatLang.

This seems to be hard to do as WeightedLatLangs are additive, and I need to display the average of the measurments in an area (i.e. an area with many points should NOT glow reder than an area with fewer points, unless the average intensity in that area is higher). Any thoughts on how to do this efficiently (O(n^2) is NOT good enough)?

Comment: If you ever figured this out please post an answer. I'm trying to do a similar thing with HeatMaps.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is trying a [Fusion Tables Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer).